# How do I scrape for users tagged in a photo on Instagram?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am using the `requests` Python library to pull the JSON data from URLs, and I have a list of posts. I would like to find out if any users are tagged in the photo itself (not in the caption, although that would be helpful too). I couldn't find anything in `window._sharedData`, and would prefer not to use parse through the HTML text. There has to be a better way. HALP

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the post's json data through the url like https://www.instagram.com/p/BWe5mIkA0t4/?__a=1 (change `BWe5mIkA0t4` to code of post you need).

Response will contains json with all tagged users by json-path `graphql.shortcode_media.edge_media_to_tagged_user`

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know what the values for `x` and `y` mean? Are they some kind of centrality values?

Comment: @TC423 I think they are tag's coordinates on image.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you!